# Issue with EJB 3.1 injected with CDI bean while running JUnit

Tags: java, junit, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I created a EJB3.1 and injected CDI bean using the @inject but facing some issues while unit testing however when tested from the servlet its working fine. I have the beans.xml in the WEB-INF folder. Below is my EJB code:

```
@Stateless
public class CdiUsingEjb {
    @Inject
    private HelloServletCDIPojo helloServletCDIPojo;

    public String greet() {
        assert helloServletCDIPojo != null;
        return helloServletCDIPojo.from();
    }
}
```

Below is my CDI bean:

```
public class HelloServletCDIPojo {
    public String from() {
        return "from HelloServletStateless CDI";
    }
}
```

I created a JUnit class:

```
public class CdiUsingEjbTest {
    @EJB
    private CdiUsingEjb cdiUsingEjb;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().bind("inject", this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(cdiUsingEjb);
    }
}
```

When I run this JUnit test I got the following error.

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$AssembleApplicationException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /Users/prasannakumar/freelanceWorkspace/javaWorkspace/TomEEExamples: couldn't start owb context
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:310)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:56)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:43)
    at in.jugchennai.prassee.ejb.HelloServletStatelessEJBTest.setup(HelloServletStatelessEJBTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Comment: Have you looked at Arquillian (www.arquillian.org)? Might be a little easier to get up and running.

Comment: I also encountered this Exception a lot. Now I have two suggestions:
* Please check if you have any compile-error anywhere. If you use Eclipse, JUnit still starts, but OpenEJB will create this exception for you
* In CdiUsingEjbTest try using `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`. @Inject will  result in an EJB injection if the target class is an EJB.